# Run gulp.js tasks given certain key strokes

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am struggling to find some sort of Node.js plugin for Gulp that allows you to run Gulp tasks given a particular keystroke combination - some sort of key binding.

For instance, a Gulp watch callback is triggered upon a `cmd+s` or `ctrl+s`, but I am looking to use a different key combination to trigger a specific gulp task.

Is this possible?

Comment: The watch callback is actually triggered by files changing on the file system - it has nothing to do with key combinations. Just wanted to clarify! Cheers.

Comment: well, truth be told, the filesystem changes are triggered by the keystrokes, but sure there may be other triggers as well

Comment: That's a way to look at it sure, but what I meant was that Gulp is _literally_ running a process that watches your files for changes. You can surely listen for keystrokes in a NodeJS process, so technically you can also do that with a Gulp task. Dunno that you could do it system-wide though, so you'd have to be in the Terminal window that is running the Gulp task for them to work. I would have to research it to code it up, perhaps someone else will come along and can help right out!